# Facebook Graph API and Generic Access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

If I understand correctly, the Graph API enables access to public pages using a generic access token. I'm finding however that many public pages are not returned in search results when using this type of token vs. a user token. I don't want users to have to go through an OAUTH dialog just to retrieve the basic properties of a public page.

This example below returns a result when using any user access token but no results when using a generic access token:

What am I doing, or understanding, incorrectly?

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=OSullivansHerndon&type=page&access_token={myuseraccesstoken}`

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=OSullivansHerndon&type=page&access_token={APPID|APP SECRET}`

Comment: You are highly recommended to accept an answer

Comment: @Oybek he got what he needed from Stack Overflow, he won't be back until he has another problem that needs solving.

Answer (score 10):

You can get a generic access token for your app that will let you look at requests where you would otherwise need an `access_token=` parameter in the Graph call. You don't need to authenticate users as the access token is for the application.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials
```

example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/nike/posts?access_token={response from above call}
```

Comment: I went wrong with Access_Token, turns out the lower case is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need  a user access token to use /search as search results use social context. If you have the page id, you can load that without any access token by just hitting /id

Comment: Actually, having tested a bit more it looks like any page that has a country or age restriction on it is not returned by the graph API if an application access token is used. All public pages without restrictions are returned just fine. I guess this is because FB cannot determine country or age based on an APP token.

Comment: so how can we solve this, on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ there's an access token which returns much better results

Comment: @RoyToledo you need to use a user access token - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ for more information. You can get additional information about access tokens by using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can get this to work without a user access token. From my limited OAUTH is the only way forward.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying GRAPH API **user** token, you simply meant that you are using **user** preferences and information .
if your intention is to fetch some public page information , then you need that page userid or username . And , if you are intention is to grab all the public data which is available for your particular user , then you have to pass oAUTH system,Since indirectly you are accessing his information which is meant public under some facebook govern rules .

Accessing public page by providing user id

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552
```

By writing the id of that page,you ca access its information. Now the question is how to access the  id of that particular page, Manually just visit that page --> photo album . on the top of that page,you will see something like "**Album  Videos**" . Just visit any of that link.now see,woola the id of that page is visible to you . something like this url

```
    http://www.facebook.com/media/albums/?id=176101909092314
```

And btw,if you are interested in performing search , then you need to specify user token. facebook do some algorithmic search for all users and track user activities . So , the result will not always the same for you and me , as an example .